# PDF compression desktop application tool

Tags: java, pdf, itext, desktop-application

I am trying to develop a desktop application(preferably) which should be able to compress PDF files to a large extent(maybe around 40%-50%).I chose JAVA and wrote the following code,but it could compress the file just by 10kb,which is undesirable.Which language should i choose,or what should i do to get the desired outcome. Pls help!

```
public class Compress {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\Srijita     thakur\\Desktop\\test\\CS_S06.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new     FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Srijita Thakur\\Desktop\\test\\op.pdf"),     PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
        stamper.getWriter().setCompressionLevel(5);
        int total = reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < total; i++) {
            reader.setPageContent(i, reader.getPageContent(i));
        }
        stamper.setFullCompression();
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: PDFs are already compressed. Good archiver may squeeze some space but it depends on a document. Try 7zip on maximum settings. It even has command line tool that can be called from your app.

Comment: Not sure it's a question of which language or even which library to use.  There are free desktop apps that do compression (like http://www.orpalis.com/products/pdfreducer/pdfreducer-free.php ) which may solve your problem.  The way they get more compression is by reducing the quality of images in the pdf.  Since images tend to bulk up a pdf file and are already compressed, the trick is to re-compress them to get maximum size reduction of the images in lossy ways which leave them still readable and visually acceptable.  I don't know of a code library in any language which does this for you.

Comment: The `setCompressionLevel(5)` won't matter much. Usually, the streams are already compressed with optimal compression. The `setFullCompression()` will compress objects and the cross-reference table, which will result in larger file size for minimal PDFs and smaller file size for PDFs with many objects. The real gain would be to compress images (resulting in a lower resolution of the images, but a much smaller file size).

Comment: ok thanks a lot :) so i should concentrate on the compression of images in the pdf files too right?